# UnrealEngine4 "backwards compatilibility": Can I view a site that uses Unreal Engine4 on a very old laptop and still see in high definition?

Tags: opengl, javascript, unreal-4, mobile, swift

## Backwards compatible?

#### The project:

I want to render a high definition model on my personal website such that it'll be rendered in the highest definition possible on any device, from a 20-year-old Gateway PC running Windows 95 to an iPhoneX. It's particularly important that it's real pretty on mobile (whatever Android and iPhone models are big these days)

#### The question:

I was thinking I'd buy an expensive desktop with GPUs to make sure I can make the app really fancy for users on a high-end desktop with nice monitors. But I'm not going to do that if the high-definition I get on my new expensive screen doesn't make it out to the app my employer is building. How does this work? Does OpenGL display the highest-definition render it can on the mobile device?

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time running any modern 3D, WebGL, or Unreal engine app on a Windows 95 PC. You might want to set your minimum spec a bit higher, or be willing to fall back on some glossy pre-rendered images when necessary.

Comment: The problem with legacy hardware in this case is not lack of GPU operations per second but lack of GPU features. When the hardware does not support certain shader operations, then it won't do them, no matter how much time you give it.

Comment: It's also the case that if one wishes to support Windows 95 PCs then one will need to deal with cases where the PC may not even have a GPU, or have a 3DFX with a mini driver that only supports a subset of OpenGL 1.0, or something horrid like that. This is certainly not a realistic objective and I'd encourage the OP to backtrack.

Answer (score 2):

A "20 year old" PC is going to be well below the minimum requirements needed to run anything built on modern Unreal 4. So no, this will not scale gracefully (or indeed, *at all*). It certainly won't render in "high definition."

To support hardware and software that old you'll likely need to fall back on entirely different technology in that scenario. Given the cost-to-benefit ratio of supporting users on such antiquated platforms, I'd strongly advise going with what was suggested in the comments and falling back to pre-rendered static images or simply moving your own minimum spec up to something in the modern era.

I'd also suggest that UE4 is a pretty heavyweight tool to use just to display a model on a webpage; you may want to investigate alternative, more web-focused technology (perhaps [three.js](https://threejs.org/), which can apparently [create a simple model view embed](https://manu.ninja/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three-js/) pretty easily).